# Bypass keycloak login system with rest api using java and generate realm/application URL

Tags: java, rest, keycloak, apiman

I am trying to integrate [apiman](https://github.com/apiman/apiman) in my project.
I am able to do following things with simple java program ( REST api ),

1. Create user for keycloak realm
2. Assign role for user.
3. Able to login in apiman with those credentials.

Things I am not being able to do ,

1. Authenticate user with rest api like keycloak does it from UI ( like the following image )
2. Generate session details and then generate URL for that realm and redirect to that project.
3. Not able able to directly login into the apiman system.

Basically I want to bypass keycloak login system with REST API using java.

[image]

I want to directly go into this screen. I am not able to find any way by which I can generate or authenticate user in keycloak and generate url for the below screen ( apiman ) and then redirect the user on the below screen using that URL.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am first experience the ApiMan. But it works this URL.

*http://localhost:8080/apimanui/api-manager/*

It turns to ApiMan Login screen.
[image]

Then I enter new user id and password
[image]

It goes to this screen.
[image]

I follow ApiMan's steps.
http://www.apiman.io/latest/download.html

```
mkdir ~/apiman-2.0.0.Final
cd ~/apiman-2.0.0.Final
curl -L https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/20.0.1.Final/wildfly-20.0.1.Final.zip -o wildfly-20.0.1.Final.zip
curl -L https://github.com/apiman/apiman/releases/download/2.0.0.Final/apiman-distro-wildfly-2.0.0.Final-overlay.zip -o apiman-distro-wildfly-2.0.0.Final-overlay.zip
unzip wildfly-20.0.1.Final.zip
unzip -o apiman-distro-wildfly-2.0.0.Final-overlay.zip -d wildfly-20.0.1.Final
cd wildfly-20.0.1.Final
./bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-apiman.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But unfortunately this is not I am looking for. I have one application which has a separate login and inside that app I am using apiman(which uses keycloak login) So I want to use only my application's login and bypass keycloak login so using java so I can directly land up in apiman from my application ( authenticating user with microservice using java ). I hope I am clear here. Sorry for misunderstanding.